# Using regular expression to get latest pip package version

Tags: bash, awk, sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to parse the output of this pip install to get the latest package version.

```
pip install package==
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package== (from versions: 19.2.0, 19.5.0, 19.6.1, 19.7.0, 19.7.1, 19.8.0, 19.9.0)
```

It should be done using bash commands (sed, awk or grep). I validate the below expression using regexr.com and it highlights all versions of the given output.

```
(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.\d+)
```

But I'm unable to get this regular expression to work with sed/awk.

Comment: Remark: `sed`, `awk` and `grep` should not be called "bash commands". Those tools are independent from the shell invoking it, they existed before `bash` and will still exist after `bash` will be gone and forgotten.

Comment: Any hint why `bash` can disappear, or it's a joke ?

Comment: Validating an expression with some online tool like regexr.com only proves that that expression behaves as desired **in that online tool**. It proves nothing about how it'll behave in any command-line tool such as awk, sed, or grep for example. To write a regexp for a given tool you need to understand which regexp variant(s) (BRE, ERE, PCRE) that specific tool understands given which options and between which delimiters and with which extensions.

Comment: There's still some people (devs, sysOps...) knowing zsh, but want to keep bash as default shell ;)

Comment: Moreover, PCRE is a subset of Perl's regex, so you can add it : `BRE, ERE, PCRE, Perl)` ;) Used the online tool **only** to explain the regex

Comment: @GillesQuenot Wrong place to start a discussion about the future of shells. I meant to illustrate why the term "bash commands" should be avoided (and I hope you can agree on that).

Comment: @GillesQuenot I couldn't be bothered learning zsh because I *don't want* to do the kinds of things that require zsh in a shell-like language - i'd rather do them in awk or perl.   I half-suspect that the creeping featuritis of bash and other shells is a bad thing because sh (and all its descendants) will never be an adequate substitute for perl or awk or python etc, but they just encourage people to write more and more complex things in "shell".   Also, the hideous ghastliness of oh-my-zsh put me off zsh for life :) even the OMZ web site is repulsively garish mess and needs too much javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only GNU [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) regex engine :

### Command line

```
pip ... |& grep -oP '.*\b\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b'
```

### Output

```
19.9.0
```

### Explanations about the regex

Check [regex101 explanations](https://regex101.com/r/pcz75U/2)

Comment: Take care, this prints the intended package version plus `19.2.3` for me due to pip telling `You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.`

Answer (score 1):

In a less complicated manner, if you are just after the latest version of pip you can do this with `cut`.

`Pip show pip | grep Version: | cut -d' ' -f2`

will result in:
`19.9.0`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package== (from versions: 19.2.0, 19.5.0, 19.6.1, 19.7.0, 19.7.1, 19.8.0, 19.9.0)' | \
    sed -e 's/^.*versions: //; s/, /\n/g; s/)//'  | \
    sort -V | tail -n1
19.9.0
```

This requires a version of sort that understands the `-V` (aka `--version-sort`) option.  GNU sort and FreeBSD sort do.  I don't know if any others do.